# tinyMce setcontent problem in IE

Tags: javascript, wordpress, internet-explorer-8, tinymce

The problem is with TinyMce library on wordpress , when run with Internet Explorer( 7 or 8).

When I add content (like "`<h1> hey </h1>`"), it adds the content in Firefox/Chrome at the right place, but in IE, it adds to the start of the page (above everything).

Here is the code I use

var txt = `"<h1> hey </h1>"`;

```
var ed = tinyMCE.getInstanceById(domElementId); // domElementId is the div ID for the textarea where i am adding the content.
ed.selection.setContent(txt);
```

Can anyone suggest what could be the reason/fix ? Thanks.

Comment: Never mind. I figured out that I dont need the selection instance. ed.setContent() works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use  `ed.setContent()` instead of using `ed.selection.setContent()`.
It will work fine in IE

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem using TinyMCE on Internet Explorer 8, here is the solution I have found:

```
var ed = tinyMCE.getInstanceById(domElementId);
*ed.focus();*
ed.selection.setContent(txt);
```

The missing part was the one where focusing.